# Kafka message ordering in partition while producer retry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

According to producer configs, there are: **retries** and **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection**. Suppose that **retries** > 0 and **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection** > 1.

Can messages arrive out of order within **ONE** partition of topic (e.g. if first message has retries, but second message delivered to broker with the first attempt)?

Or do out of order only happen across several partitions of topic, but within partition order is preserved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set `retries` to more than 0 and `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to more than 1, then yes messages can arrive out of order on the broker even if they are for the same partition.

You can also have duplicates if for example a message is correctly added to the Kafka logs and an error happens when sending the response back to the client.

Since Kafka 0.11, you can use the Idempotent producer to solve these 2 issues. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics

Comment: If I have `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` set to `5` and `retries` set to `3` and `enable.idempotence` set to `true` plus `acks` set to `all` - will that maintain order?

Comment: If you use the idempotent producer, retries will not reorder messages

Comment: Got it, let me try that

Answer (score 1):

As per latest update documentation, you can have maximum 5 `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` and Kafka can maintain order for this.

Comment: This is true and it's because the broker holds the last 5 sequencing numbers sent from each producer when idempotent producing is enabled. For Kafka 2.5+  the  `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` defaults to five as well (and also the highest value supported by the idempotent producer bc first line)

Comment: So if I have `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` set to `5` and `retries` set to `3` and `enable.idempotence` set to `true` plus `acks` set to `all` - will that maintain order?

Comment: @NickDiv Yes, it does. Have a look https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_enable.idempotence

Comment: @Mahan Thank you. I tried the above setting and observed the sequence is maintained.